# Search for zero or one occurrence of word in SQL row

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-like, regexp-like

I want to search for the occurrence of words in a database row. I use SQLite as a database. The search needs to be case-insensitive.

Let's say row x is `Hello. Today is Monday` and I want to search for `Hello Monday Bye` and still return the row x because the `Hello` and `Monday` exist in the row.

I used Like operator `%Hello%Tuesday%Bye%` but this defiantly doesn't work and I can't use `Glob` because it's not case-insensitive. Any suggestion, how can I do the search?

Also, the order shouldn't matter and `Monday Hello` should return a row as well

Comment: What do you mean by *zero* occurrence? If none of the words exist in the column what do you want in the results?

Comment: if non of them exists I want to return an empty result  forpas

Answer (score 1):

You can [extend SQLite with regular expressions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#regexp) and then use:

```
where col regexp replace($searchfor, ' ', '|')
```

This will return any time there is a match with any of the values.

Answer (score 0):

First create a recursive `CTE` to split the string `'Hello Monday Bye'` which contains the words you search for.
Then join it to the table:

```
with cte as (
    select null word, 'Hello Monday Bye' || ' ' rest
    union all
    select substr(rest, 1, instr(rest, ' ') - 1),
           substr(rest, instr(rest, ' ') + 1)
    from cte
    where length(rest) > 0
  )
select distinct t.* 
from tablename t inner join cte c
on t.col like '%' || c.word || '%'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=bfbed74f283f8cb30b0c5017b195c8ff).